# ROS - Compilation fails due to Bzip2 libraries

Tags: compilation, makefile, libraries, ros, bzip2

I'm trying to compile a package using Ros Indigo. I'm using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. The BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR are missing. When I run the make command, I get the following error:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbag_storage'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/rosbag_storage)
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):   Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR) Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBZip2.cmake:47 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   ros_comm/rosbag_storage/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! Invoking "cmake" failed
```

How can I add these libraries?

Comment: Install the bzip2 package? How this is done is OS specific. You did not tell us on which OS you are.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using Raspbian an operative system based on Debian and optimized for the Raspberry Pi board. I've installed bzip2 package.

Comment: I specified Ros (robot operating system) by the way which runs only on linux kernel based OS

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to install [libbz2-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libbz2-dev), it should contain the header files required to compile your package.

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu, use:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```